# Configuration error

Tags: asp.net, configuration, windows-authentication

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 24:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 25:         -->
Line 26:        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
Line 27:     
Line 28:        <!--
```

Comment: That's just an error message. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET engine is suggesting a solution to this problem and it is the most common cause for this error:

In the IIS Snap-in (Inetmgr.msc), right click your website, go to the properties dialog and on the Virtual directory tab, under "Application Settings", click "Create" to create an application for the web app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are multiple web.config files lying around in a single virtual directory. Just search the virtual directory, and see if that is the case; if yes, then remove the unnecessary web.config file or make the directory containing that web.config as a virtual directory too.