# Issues occured when changing a Project to a Website in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, virtual-directory

After changing a Project to Website, i got an error while running the application.The error is as follows:-

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition ='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in ISS.

How can i solve this problem?ISS is installed in my system.Then what could be the reason for this?

Please help...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746599/configuration-error/746620

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your virtual directory isn't set to run as an application.

Go into IIS, find the virtual directory that contains your project, go into properties for that folder and in the virtual directory tab you'll see 'Application Settings' near the bottom. Click the 'Create' button down here to set the website up as an application.

Answer (score 1):

In the IIS Manager snap-in, go to your web site property page, then select create application.